# How does HTML5 server sent events works?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to understand how does HTML5 server side event works ? In the below code why would it not print Hello ? But if i remove the comments on the server side time line in php it would work and keep displaying the server side time?

HTML5

```
<div id="result"></div>

        <script>

    if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
      {
      var source=new EventSource("php/demo_sse.php");
      source.onmessage=function(event)
        {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
        };
      }
    else
      {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
      }
     </script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "Hello";
//echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache and reload the page?

Comment: Yes indeed i am also using incognito mode in chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one detail, which you must be aware, this is the

**Event Stream Format**

Sending an event stream from the source is a matter of constructing a plain text response, served with a `text/event-stream` Content-Type, that follows the `SSE` (Server-Sent Events) format. In its basic form, the response should contain a "data:" line, followed by your message, **followed by two** `\n` characters to end the stream:

```
data: My message\n\n
```

**Multiline Data**

If your message is longer, you can break it up by using multiple "data:" lines. Two or more consecutive lines beginning with "data:" will be treated as a single piece of data, meaning only one message event will be fired.

Each line should end in a single `\n` (except for the last, which should end with two). The result passed to your message handler is a single string concatenated by newline characters. For example:

```
data: first line\n
data: second line\n\n
```

will produce `first line\nsecond line` in `e.data`.

One could then use `e.data.split('\n').join('')` to reconstruct the message sans `\n` characters.

So much of the theory, back to your problem, just write:

```
echo "Hello"."\n\n";
```

EDIT:

**Controlling the Reconnection-timeout**

The browser attempts to reconnect to the source **roughly 3 seconds** after each connection is closed. You can change that timeout by including a line beginning with `retry:`, followed by the **number of milliseconds** to wait before trying to reconnect.

The following example attempts a reconnect after 10 seconds:

```
retry: 10000\n
data: hello world\n\n
```

**Cancel an Event Stream**

Normally, the browser auto-reconnects to the event source when the connection is closed, but that behavior can be canceled from either the client or server.

To cancel a stream from the client, simply call:

`source.close();`

To cancel a stream from the server, respond with a non `text/event-stream` Content-Type or return an HTTP status other than `200 OK` (e.g. `404 Not Found`).

Both methods will prevent the browser from re-establishing the connection.

Official documentation is [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/) and a word of security is [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#authors).

Comment: i never knew about the format thanks a lot. one quick question for you it runs every second i beleive i am not sure the exact time ? but what determines that ? looks like it will run for infinite number of time ? Is there a way i can restrict that ? for example i only want it to print if there is an update in the database

Comment: thanks thanks is there a documentation link i can follow for more details ? If you can link me to that doc that would be great help